# How to convert style trigger WPF to UWP

Tags: uwp, styles, uwp-xaml

I want convert to WPF triigger to UWP. How to convert UWP, because the trigger is not available in the UWP

```
<TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit">
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

</TextBlock

Comment: Does the following answer work, and do you have any updates for this thread ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want convert to WPF triigger to UWP. How to convert UWP, because the trigger is not available in the UWP

For UWP platform, you could use [XamlBehaviors](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki) [DataTriggerBehavior](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior) to implement Trigger functuion. But I have to say, UWP TextBlock has no IsEnabled property. So the following code using IsTextSelectionEnabled property to make a sample.

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="Text"
    IsTextSelectionEnabled="False"
    Text="Hello World !">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
            Binding="{Binding IsTextSelectionEnabled, ElementName=Text}"
            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
            Value="False">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Text}"
                Value="Red" />
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>

        <Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior
            Binding="{Binding IsTextSelectionEnabled, ElementName=Text}"
            ComparisonCondition="Equal"
            Value="True">
            <Interactions:ChangePropertyAction
                PropertyName="Foreground"
                TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Text}"
                Value="Green" />
        </Interactions:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

UWP TextBox has IsEnabled property, and if you want to edit Foreground for disable state. you need to update the default style and change Disabled `VisualState`, And TextBox disable foreground has specific resource [`TextControlForegroundDisabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox?view=winrt-22621#control-style-and-template), the easy way is using the following to override the default one in app.xaml

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundDisabled" Color="SlateBlue" />
```